# RFID library issue

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I am having some strange issue. I am using Linkit One board, which is a based on Arduino.

I am using rfid reader RC522 which is cheapest and most common.

I cant get its official library get it work. I tried to search for problem or differences but nothing help. I am looking for some to take a fresh look because its been 4 days and i am stuck.

Not Working https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid

Working (this is full ino in single file) http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/ggrfid_en_ino.txt